# Haskell Show bug?

Tags: haskell, types, show

So in one file I have

```
import Data.String
import MyShow

data Tree a b = Leaf a | Branch b (Tree a b) (Tree a b)

instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (Tree a b) where
   show (Branch n t1 t2) = "(" ++ myshow t1 ++ myshow n ++ myshow t2 ++ ")"
   show (Leaf l) = myshow l

newtype MyString = MyString String

instance Show MyString where
    show (MyString s) = s
```

and in another file called MyShow.hs I have

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
module MyShow where

class MyShow a where
    myshow :: a -> String

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} MyShow String where
    myshow s = s
    
instance Show a => MyShow a where
    myshow = show
```

When I load the first file in ghci, `(Branch "+" (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2)` shows `(1"+"2)` and when I try `"(" ++ myshow (Leaf 1) ++ myshow "+" ++ myshow (Leaf 2) ++ ")"`, that shows `(1+2)`, which is what I want.

What is the reason for this discrepancy and how do I fix it?

Comment: So you have `OverloadedStrings` enabled by any chance? Can you try `Branch ("+" :: String) (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2)`?

Comment: Your instance of `Show (Tree a b)` is problematic, as the constraint doesn't require that `myshow` be defined for any of the values you apply it to, only `show`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your definition of `Show (Tree a b)` only requires `a` and `b` to have `Show` instances, not `MyShow` instances. As such (and I don't think I can explain precisely why), the instance of `Show a => MyShow a` takes precedence over `MyShow String`, because the type checker doesn't know that `a` having a `MyShow` instance is a possibility.

If you change the constraint to

```
instance (MyShow a, MyShow b) => Show (Tree a b) where
```

then `show (Branch "+" (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2))` will work as expected: `myshow "+"` will use the `MyShow String` instance, not the `Show a => MyShow a` instance.

Comment: To explain precisely why, look at the instance as a kind of type-level function, with constraints as parameters and the instance itself as result. Since this "function" does not take `MyShow` instances as parameters, it has no way of accessing them. But it doesn't error out, because, luckily, there is a universal  `MyShow` instance that it can construct out of the `Show` instances that it does have.

Comment: This kind of problem is one of the reasons overlapping instances should be avoided if at all possible btw.

Comment: Yes, `OverlappingInstances` are IMHO a misfeature, the rules are not "simple" enough to avoid mistakes.